# Can not set thumbnail for home page (it is also shop page) when sharing on Facebook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, thumbnails

My website use the shop page as the front page. I already set featured image for that page. 
When I sharing the link of my shop page [www.shopgiayhd.com/shop](http://www.shopgiayhd.com/shop) I got the thumbnail as the featured image I set.
But when I sharing my web link [www.shopgiayhd.com](http://www.shopgiayhd.com), it uses the last product image as the thumbnail.

I tried to add the meta property og:image at the `<head>...</head>`. It works but it affects all other links such as category, single product. I don't want like that.

Please help me. Thank you so much in advance

Comment: You will need to add a conditional statement around the meta tag so that it only sets it on the homepage. Alternatively, you could use a plugin, like [Yoast SEO](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/), to have more control over it.

Comment: I also set in @Yoast SEO but it is unsuccessful. I don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in header if( is_home() || is_front_page() ) check then output og:image for just homepage.

Comment: `<head>` 
 `if(is_home() || is_front_page()) {`
  `<meta property="og:image" content="http://shopgiayhd.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Slide_web-1.jpg"/>;`
  `<?php wp_head(); ?>`
 `}`
 `else {`
  `<?php wp_head(); ?>`
 `}`
`</head>`

I try this one. but it makes nothing. Anything wrong?
Thank you

Comment: You need to do it like this

`<?php if(is_home() || is_front_page()) { ?>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://shopgiayhd.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Slide_web-1.jpg"/>
<?php } ?>`

Comment: Thank you so much. It works well. I have to add something more but I know the basic to modify now.